# Accumulating gradients inside tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, backpropagation, gradient

I'm trying to accumulate gradients from different batches within tensorflow before performing backpropagation. Let's say, I have 10 batches of 10 samples each and input them on my neural net. for each of the batches i want to get the gradients and sum them up and them perform backpropagation with the summed gradients.

Does anyone know a simple way to do that? As of now I am getting the gradients and summing them up from outside but I don't think this is the best way.

Comment: Are you looking for `tf.test.compute_gradient`? https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/test.html#compute_gradient

Comment: What's your application here?

Comment: I'm using it for some reinforcement learning algorithm. The idea behind is to accumulate data from different batches and accumulate the gradients before backprop using rmsprop scaling.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add the gradients of the batches to variables, and then use the values of those variables as the gradients when applying the update.